# NSubstitute IEnumerable Returns

Tags: nsubstitute

I've a class that has a `IEnumerable<object>` property:

```
interface ICore {

    IEnumerable<object> enumerable { get; }

}
```

I need to substitute the return values of this `IEnumerable<object>`. I've rtied with `Returns`, nevertheless, I'm getting a message telling me it's not available on an `IEnumerable`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSubstitute works with the `IEnumerable` interface perfectly fine. Here's an example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NSubstitute.Acceptance.Specs.FieldReports
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SO_42159342
    {
        public interface ICore
        {
            IEnumerable<object> Enumerable { get; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var sub = Substitute.For<ICore>();
            sub.Enumerable.Returns(Enumerable.Empty<object>());
            sub.Enumerable.Returns(new List<object>());
            sub.Enumerable.Returns(_ => new[] {new object()});

            Assert.True(sub.Enumerable.Count() == 1);
        }
    }
}
```